# What does the command "cpan reports" do exactly?

Tags: perl, cpan

I tried to install Moose in perl 5.32.0 with the command `cpan install Moose`.  The installation failed, with the following message:

```
Result: FAIL
Failed 448/478 test programs. 12/30 subtests failed.
Makefile:2047: recipe for target 'test_dynamic' failed
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  ETHER/Moose-2.2013.tar.gz
13 dependencies missing (Class::Load,Class::Load::XS,Data::OptList,Devel::OverloadInfo,Dist::CheckConflicts,Module::Runtime::Conflicts,Package::DeprecationManager,Package::Stash,Package::Stash::XS,Params::Util,Sub::Exporter,Sub::Identify,Test::CleanNamespaces); additionally test harness failed
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports ETHER/Moose-2.2013.tar.gz
```

I tried the command `cpan reports ETHER/Moose-2.2013.tar.gz`, and somehow this installed Moose correctly.  What happened here?  What does `cpan reports` do exactly?  Is this the same as App::cpanreports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*You asked why using `cpan reports ...` instead of `cpan install ...` helped. This answers that. brian d foy's explains why `cpan reports ...` wasn't what you wanted to execute.*]

It tries to install a module named `reports`.

---

The syntax for `cpan` is

```
cpan [options] <module_name> [<module_name> ...]
```

The operation is specified through options. The default operator is `-i` (install).

---

**`cpan install Moose`**

This command tries to install two distributions:

- The newest one containing the module `install`.

  A [dummy module](https://metacpan.org/pod/install) by this name was created, so this should not produce any errors.

  Newer versions of `cpan` simply ignore this erroneous request.
- The newest one containing the module `Moose`.

  This is currently `ETHER/Moose-2.2013.tar.gz`.

---

**`cpan reports ETHER/Moose-2.2013.tar.gz`**

This command tries to install two distributions:

- The newest one containing the module `reports`.

  There's no module named `reports`, so that part fails.

  ```
  >(error): Could not expand [reports]. Check the module name.
  >(info): I can suggest names if you install one of Text::Levenshtein::XS, Text::Levenshtein::Damerau::XS, Text::Levenshtein, and Text::Levenshtein::Damerau::PP
  >(info): and you provide the -x option on invocation.
  >(error): Skipping reports because I couldn't find a matching namespace.
  ```
- `ETHER/Moose-2.2013.tar.gz`

---

So,

```sh
cpan install Moose
```

is merely a bad way of writing

```sh
cpan Moose
```

Also,

```sh
cpan reports ETHER/Moose-2.2013.tar.gz
```

is merely a bad way of writing

```sh
cpan ETHER/Moose-2.2013.tar.gz
```

Currently, this should currently be equivalent to

```sh
cpan Moose
```

In other words, there's no difference between the command you claimed didn't work and the one you claimed worked.

Comment: Interesting. I tried running `cpan Moose` in a fresh local::lib. I got the same problem. The I ran the same command again. And now Moose was installed correctly. So for some reason I have to install Moose twice. Which is a totally different problem.

Answer (score 3):

The error message there refers to something you can do in the CPAN.pm shell, and the `cpan` command doesn't have anything to map to that. Even if it did, it wouldn't look the same.

`cpan` with no arguments puts you into the CPAN.pm shell, and it's there that you can issue commands (such as `install` and whatnot). For `reports`, you need to install LWP and CPAN::Reporter first:

```
% cpan LWP CPAN::Reporter
...
% cpan
cpan[1]> reports ETHER/Moose-2.2013.tar.gz
Distribution: E/ET/ETHER/Moose-2.2013.tar.gz
Fetching 'http://www.cpantesters.org/show/Moose.json'...DONE

2.2013:
 +PASS 5.28.0 on SunOS/Solaris 2.11 (i86pc-solaris-64)
 +PASS 5.28.3 on GNU/Linux 5.4.34-0-lts (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.22.4 on GNU/Linux 5.4.0-26-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.26.0 on FreeBSD 12.1-release (i386-freebsd-64int)
 +PASS 5.26.0 on SunOS/Solaris 2.11 (i86pc-solaris-64)
```

However, it's probably easier to look on [CPAN Testers](https://www.cpantesters.org) to see the results for a particular module.